# Genrate Url with current domain from input type file element using Javascripts..?

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have an element which has input type file I just want create full URL through image with including domain name from where I am uploading  Using JavaScript..?

**Example:**

```
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
```

**Expected Output:**

https://stackoverflow.com/my_uplaod_imageFullPath.extension

I want to thank everyone in advance and it will be very kind if you give appropriate opinion on this. This is very important for me I searched and tried a lot but I was able to get what I want.

Comment: Have you tried [`document.location.origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location)?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl  By provided your method I tried and get  this `https://www.w3schools.com/image_2022_08_30T11_29_46_887Z.png` that is not performing well as per the requirement. 
Could you please give me example of it where I would see how concatenate file name with **document.location.origin** . .?